How to set git not to fiddle with newline on both windows and linux
I'm facing some issue when using a project tracked by git on both windows and linux. As suggested on other questions on windows I have
core.autocrlf=false
core.eol=<blank>

On Linux I have the defaults
core.autocrlf=<blank>
core.eol=<blank>

this is my .gitattributes used in the project
#general rule - ignore eol
* -text

#src
*.c     text diff=cpp
*.cc    text diff=cpp
*.cxx   text diff=cpp
*.cpp   text diff=cpp
*.cpi   text diff=cpp
*.c++   text diff=cpp
*.hpp   text diff=cpp
*.h     text diff=cpp
*.h++   text diff=cpp
*.hh    text diff=cpp
*.CPP   text diff=cpp
*.HPP   text diff=cpp
*.cs    text eol=crlf

# Unix files (LF)
*.sh            text eol=lf
Makefile        text eol=lf
makefile        text eol=lf
MAKEFILE        text eol=lf
make*           text eol=lf


# Windows files (CRLF)

*.sln    text eol=crlf
*.csproj text eol=crlf
*.suo    text eol=crlf
*.vbproj text eol=crlf
*.bat    text eol=crlf
*.vcxproj    text eol=crlf
*.vcproj     text eol=crlf
*.dbproj     text eol=crlf
*.fsproj     text eol=crlf
*.lsproj     text eol=crlf
*.wixproj    text eol=crlf
*.modelproj  text eol=crlf
*.sqlproj    text eol=crlf
*.wwaproj    text eol=crlf

*.xproj      text eol=crlf
*.props      text eol=crlf
*.filters    text eol=crlf
*.vcxitems   text eol=crlf

# common binary files
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.gif binary
*.com binary
*.exe binary
*.out binary
*.dll binary
*.a binary
*.lo binary
*.so binary
*.lai   binary
*.la    binary
*.slo binary
*.lib binary
*.class binary
*.dylib binary

# Precompiled Headers
*.gch   binary
*.pch   binary

# Ignoring whitespaces changes on edits
*.c -whitespace
*.cs -whitespace
*.cpp -whitespace
*.h -whitespace
*.hpp -whitespace

# Git LFS for big files
*.dll filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.pdb filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# customized merge strategy for configuration files 
.config merge=ours
*.user merge=ours


### From here JAVA ###

*.properties    text auto

# Unix (LF)

*.xml       text
*.java          text diff=java
*.kt            text diff=kotlin
*.groovy        text diff=java
*.scala         text diff=java
*.gradle        text diff=java
*.gradle.kts    text diff=kotlin



# config file merge strategy 
*.iml merge=ours

# Ignores whitespace changes
*.java -whitespace

# Git LFS for big files
*.[jew]ar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text


# Common build-tool wrapper scripts ('.cmd' versions are handled by 'Common.gitattributes')
mvnw            text eol=lf
gradlew         text eol=lf
# Apply override to all files in the directory
*.md linguist-detectable

# Other files handled as text
*.txt       text auto
*.json      text eol=lf
*.yml       text eol=lf
*.yaml      text eol=lf
.git*       text 
*.html      text 
*.htm       text eol=crlf
*.css           text diff=css
*.scss          text diff=css
*.js            text
*.jsp           text
*.jspf          text
*.jspx          text
*.properties    text
*.tld           text
*.tag           text
*.tagx          text

and this is my .editorconfig (But I dont think it is used on windows given I use VS2015)
root = true

[*]
#end_of_line = lf # commented out not to conflict with git
charset = utf-8
insert_final_newline = true

# Makefile using tab
[{Makefile,makefile,MAKEFILE,app.mak,lib.mak}]
indent_style = tab
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.bat]
end_of_line = crlf

[*.{sh}]
end_of_line = lf

[*.{c,h,cpp,hpp,java,php,js,json,sh}]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
max_line_length = 120

What I'm finding is that on linux also files like project.sln (a visual studio solution) git diff | cat -v reports newline conversion (^M is removed after the lines).
Also all other files are reported as modified (and the only differences are new lines).
How do I avoid linux reporting "fake" changes?
What am I missing?

If you remove all those EOL settings, git won't mess up with EOLs... Whatever you feed it with, it will accept and it will put out on the working tree when you checkout.

Git will, otherweise I wouldn't have had to figure all this mess and lastly write here here.
